# What are the methods for keeping receiving json data from HTTP without requesting every time?

Tags: http

Suppose I want to 'subscribe' to a service which will give me the dollar price every second. Making an HTTP request every second, when multiplied by millions of clients, will stress the server.

I know of a technique where you call the server once, and it never finishes responding with the HTTP request. It always send more info in the same connection. What is this technique called?

Is there another way of doing that, without opening my router port? That is, without turning the client into a server, like using webhooks?

Comment: You are probably referring to "[push technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)". A similar question as been asked and answered [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/112072).